# Error compiling typescript with Vue.js TS2352

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

This is my `window.ts`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

interface BrowserWindow extends Window {
  app: Vue
}

const browserWindow = window as BrowserWindow
export default browserWindow
```

I keep getting this error while compiling

```
TS2352: Conversion of type 'Window & typeof globalThis' to type 'BrowserWindow' may 
be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, 
convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Property 'app' is missing in type 'Window & typeof globalThis' but required in type 'BrowserWindow'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message describes, cast your `windows` to `unknown` and then to `BrowserWindow`:

```js
const browserWindow = window as unknown as BrowserWindow
```